# Is there a way to dinamically set the labelLimit property of an Altair Axis depending on the longest tick label?

Tags: altair

The question refers to an horizontal bar chart in Altair with text labels on the Y axis and numbers on the X axis. For context, the text labels on the Y axis are table names and the X axis shows how long it took to build that table.

The chart is almost done, the only thing that is bothering me is that long table names get clipped (see screenshot). Looking at the [Altair documentation](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.Axis.html) I have found the **labelLimit** property of an Axis that determines the maximum lenght of axis tick labels in pixels and defaults to 180 pixel.

Is there a way of dynamically determining the width in pixels of the longest label I have in my data to automatically set the **labelLimit** to that to avoid clipping?

This is how I am building the chart (I manually set the limit to 300 for testing):
`chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(x=alt.X('execution_time:Q', sort=None), y=alt.Y('name', axis=alt.Axis(labelLimit=300)).sort('-x'))`

And here's a screenshot that shows how the middle label is getting clipped.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9LZr.png)

Thank you in advance for your help!

The only way I have found to solve the issue is to manually set the **labelLimit** property of the Y axis tick labels to a big enough number so that nothing gets clipped, but I'd like to find a more elegant solution.

Comment: I don't think there is anything automatic so you would have to estimate the pixles per character for different characters. There might be something in PIL or similar libraries that can help

Comment: Doesn't ```labelLimit=0``` solve this?

Comment: @debbes that worked! There was no mention of that behaviour in the docs so I hadn't thought about it. Thanks a lot!